# Small issue with Electron Packager and NightmareJS

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I am using NightmareJS with Electron.  Everything works as expected in development. However, when I pack my application with electron packager, I get a new window every time when I try to run nightmareJS code.

I have already set NightmareJS property `show` to `false` - so I have no idea what is going wrong after packaging my app.

I have three files;  `main.js`, `script.js` and `index.html`

Please have a look and let me know why I am getting new window on click of button in `index.html` file after packaging, but not in development.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button>Click Me</button>

    <script>
        var electron = require('electron');
        var ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
            ipcRenderer.send('message','Hello');
        });        

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const scraper = require('./js/script')
let win;

function createWindow(){

    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width:935,
        height:513,
        frame:false,
        resizable:false,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    });

    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

    win.on('closed', function(){
        win = null;
    });
}

ipcMain.on('message',(event, data)=>{    
     scraper.scrape();
});

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function(){
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', function(){
    if(win==null){
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

**script.js**

```
module.exports.scrape = () => {
  const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
  const nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: false,
    electronPath: require('electron').app.getPath('exe')
  })

  nightmare
    .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
    .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
    .click('#search_button_homepage')
    .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
    .end()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Search failed:', error)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting issues after packaging of the app, then there is a pretty good chance that it is electron-packager issue.

I have used electron-packager previously and I faced few issues with that. Now I am using electron-builder which is much more mature and easy to use.

What I would suggest that you try packaging your app with electron-builder and see if you are getting the same issue again.

You can try to look at the packaging configurations of electron-builder by [zulip/zulip-electron](https://github.com/zulip/zulip-electron/blob/32a21889fbe7d96eea078c003e79d81be0ac3aa1/package.json#L39)

Comment: The output is still the same with electron-builder.  On click of button, I am getting new window.  Will you mind having a look?